# Error after flashing the example on my esp32-c3 board

Tags: memory, programming, microprocessor, flash, esp32

I am currently trying to develop software for a board I created a short time ago with the esp32c3 as microprocessor.
I followed all the steps of the espressif '[get started](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32c3/get-started/linux-macos-setup.html#get-started-first-steps)'.

I firstly set the automatic recognition of the memory, I can load the program but when I connect via putty by serial I get the following error:

*E (241) spi_flash: Detected size(512k) smaller than the size in the binary image header(2048k). Probe failed.*

When I manually set my memory size (4MB) in the config menu, I get the exact same error, only with the size I have entered:

*E (241) spi_flash: Detected size(512k) smaller than the size in the binary image header(4096k). Probe failed.*

I am using a [4mb windbond as memory](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811101710_Winbond-Elec-W25X40CLSNIG_C19617.pdf), but I see that it is divided into 8 blocks of 512kb. So I guess it is reading a single block only.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Your SPI Flash seems to be only 4 Mega**bit**, which is 512 Kilobyte.

Comment: Oh, I just screwed that. Probably I would need to get a new flash.